# send js string to external php file

Tags: javascript, php

I want to send a javascript string from an external file to a php file. So far I have tried everything.

**My Script.js**

```
    function doWork(string){
        if (httpObject != null) {
           httpObject.open("GET", "index.php?myvar=" + string, true);
           httpObject.send(null);
        }
    }
```

**My index.php**

```
    if (isset($_GET['myvar'])) {
        echo ($_GET['myvar']);
        $string = $_GET['myvar'];
    }
```

This is not getting me anything. Would really appreciate help.

Comment: "So far I have tried everything." What have you tried? Can you give an example for `string`?

Comment: How can you tell that it isn't getting you anything? What are you doing to try to examine the output of the PHP program?

Comment: Can you check your javascript request using firebug or some dev. tool? are you trying to GET the string from another domain?

Comment: An example for string is 'Home'. I am using echo to display the string. And no it is in the same domain but two different files.

Comment: `echo` will not *display* the string. It will output it in the HTTP response. What are you doing to examine that response?

Comment: Once home is set the $string variable is supposed to change the file that is displayed.                     `if($string != 'Home') {
      include 'files.php';
     } else {
      include 'Home.php';
     }`

Comment: @Quentin how can i get that string

Comment: I suggest you read though [these examples](https://web.archive.org/web/20131207023757/http://www.jibbering.com/2002/4/httprequest.html)